# split function returning unexpected result

Tags: python, split

I have a file having many lines of data separated by comma like

```
Mary,F,6919
Anna,F,2698
Emma,F,2034
Elizabeth,F,1852
Margaret,F,1658
Minnie,F,1653
```

I am reading the text file and trying to split the words

```
filename = 1880.txt
with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.split() for x in content]
```

It gives the result as

```
['Mary,F,9889', 'Anna,F,4283', 'Emma,F,2764', 'Elizabeth,F,2680', 'Minnie,F,2372']
```

I expect the content variable should return each line with data split at comma like

```
[('Mary','F','9889'), ('Anna','F','4283'), ('Emma','F','2764'), ('Elizabeth','F','2680'), ('Minnie,'F','2372')]
```

where is my mistake using the split function?

Comment: Split? I don't see you splitting anything?

Comment: It appears that you're not using `split` at all.

Comment: Everything looks as expected. Maybe change your expectations by reading the docs?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer should be

```
filename = 1880.txt
with open(filename) as f:
content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip().split(',') for x in content]
```

Comment: I have modified as content = [x.split(',') for x in content] , but in result is [['Mary', 'F', '9889\n'], ['Anna', 'F', '4283\n'],... extra to be avoided \n ?

Comment: Use  `content = [x.strip().rstrip('\n').split(',') for x in content]`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the file object once, applying `str.strip` to remove the trailing `'\n'`:

```
new_data = [tuple(i.strip('\n').split(',')) for i in open('filename.txt')]
```

Comment: thanks , it worked 
content = [x.strip('\n').split(',') for x in content]